# What does roslaunch do while loading yaml config files?

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am slightly new to ROS. From what I understand it loads the entries of the file as rosparams onto the parameter server.

So if my launch file contains the following line:
`<rosparam file="$(find my_navigation)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />`

And the yaml config file contains:
`TrajectoryPlannerROS: max_vel_x: 0.1 min_vel_x: 0.05`

Is it equivalent to entering the following in the launch file:
`

`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188474/what-does-roslaunch-do-while-loading-yaml-config-files?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; that is correct.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1